# How many football teams have won the treble?

Tags: football, history, trivia, records

Winning the "treble" means winning the three main titles of the season:

1. Continental championship (e.g. Champions League)
2. National league championship
3. National cup title

How many teams in the history of football have won the treble?

Comment: Everton did the treble in 1985!

Comment: @user6300 It was not the Champions League Everton won in 1985, it was 'just' the UEFA Cup Winners' Cup.

Comment: @Phab still counts as a treble

Comment: Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treble_(association_football)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The following teams have won a treble:

1. Celtic - 1967
2. Ajax - 1972
3. PSV - 1988
4. Manchester United - 1999
5. FC Barcelona (2) - 2009, 2015
6. Internazionale - 2010
7. Bayern München (2) - 2013, 2020
8. Manchester City - 2023

Comment: I'll add link to a Wikipedia article relevant for this: [Treble (association football)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treble_%28association_football%29#Continental_Treble).

Answer (score 19):

If instead of "European Championship" you mean the continental championship of the continent where the team is located (since it is not possible for any team outside of Europe to win the European championship) then the answer is:

- Santos (Brazil) - 1962
- Celtic (Scotland) - 1967
- Englebert (DR Congo) - 1967
- Cruz Azul (Mexico) - 1969, 1997
- Ajax Amsterdam (Netherlands) - 1972
- Vita Club (Zaire) - 1973
- MC Algiers (Algeria) - 1976
- Liverpool (England) - 1984
- Defence Force (Trinidad & Tobago) - 1985
- PSV Eindhoven (Netherlands) - 1988
- Manchester United (England) - 1999
- Hearts of Oak (Ghana) - 2000
- Al-Ahly (Egypt) - 2006, 2007, 2020
- Auckland City (New Zealand) - 2006, 2014, 2015, 2020
- Waitakere United (New Zealand) - 2008
- Barcelona (Spain) - 2009, 2015
- Internazionale (Italy) - 2010
- Esperance (Tunisia) - 2011
- Bayern Munich (Germany) - 2013, 2020
- Hienghène Sport (New Caledonia) - 2019
- Al Hilal (Saudi Arabia) - 2020
- Manchester City (England) - 2023

Comment: +1 for making the answer much more appropriate for the worldwide audience, although it does seem to decrease the standard of the club/team that has accomplished this feat.

Comment: I'm not sure whether Liverpool could be considered to have won the Treble in '84. They only won the League Cup, which isn't considered to be England's primary cup competition.